# Rails 3. Active Record. Logging. Display SQL-transaction blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, activerecord, transactions

How can I have the SQL transaction blocks in my Rails logger?

For example, I have the following transaction:

```
>> Client.transaction do
?> Client.find_by_name('Pavel').withdraw(2000)
>> Client.find_by_name('Elena').deposit(2000)
>> raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
>> end
=> nil
```

After it finishes its work the next lines will have been added to *log/development.log*:

```
SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "balances" SET "amount" = 8000 WHERE ("balances"."id" = 1)
SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "balances" SET "amount" = 7000 WHERE ("balances"."id" = 2)
```

However, the aforementioned transaction doesn't update a database and the SQL output makes confusion.

It should be like the following:

```
BEGIN;
  UPDATE "balances" SET "amount" = 8000 WHERE ("balances"."id" = 1);
  UPDATE "balances" SET "amount" = 7000 WHERE ("balances"."id" = 2);
ROLLBACK;
```

How can I acquire a correct SQL output while I'm using transactions?

Thanks.

Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.6;

Ruby 1.9.2;

Ruby on Rails 3.0.1;

Sqlite 3.7.3.

Answer (score 0):

It's not implement in ActiveRecord actually. You need made some feature-request on ActiveRecord bugtracker or do yourself the patch or try create a plugin to do that.